# induced representations and faithful actions

Tags: representation-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$. We look at complex representations of $H$ and $G$.

Recall that an action is faithful if the kernel of the action is trivial.

Let $W$ be a complex representation of $H$, and let $V = \mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W)$ be the induced representation.

Assume that $V$ is a faithful and irreducible $G$-representation.

Does this imply that $H$-action on $W$ is faithful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $W$ need not be faithful.

Take $G = (C_p \times C_p)\rtimes C_2$ where $p$ is prime, and $C_2$ acts by switching the factors, and let $H = C_p \times C_p$.

Let $W$ be an irreducible $1$-dimensional representation where the first factor of $H$ acts trivially, and the second factor acts by a non-trivial character. Clearly this is not faithful.  I claim $Ind_H^G(W)$ is irreducible and faithful.

To see it's irreducible note that it is just a direct sum of two non-isomorphic representations of $H$ which are exchanged by $C_2$.

To see it's faithful note that it is a direct sum of two $H$-invariant subspaces.  On the first one the first factor of $H$ acts trivially, but the second acts nontrivially.  On the second one the first factor acts non-trivially but the second factor acts trivially.  It follows that any element of $H$ acts non-trivially on (at least) one of these subspaces and thus nontrivially on $V$.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful.